# How to shrink root partition and extend another

Tags: linux-mint, partition, root

[image]

Here is GParted. The 4 partitions on the left are for windows 10, and the 3 on right are linux mint. The large green one is C: for windows, and I believe the large blue one is root for linux. I do not know how the root partition got over 82 GB, I want to shrink it down to maybe 12 and use all of the remaining for C: in windows. I am aware I will probably need to boot into a live session. Is this possible? will windows accept the addition to C:? Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to guess which partition is which, as they're labelled underneath the diagram (for example, `/dev/sda6` is `/`). You can shrink `/dev/sda6` but you'll also need to move the start to give space for `/dev/sda4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

If you only shrink the ext4 partition, Windows will not see any changes to C:, you will have to increase the size of sda4 too, which may be more troublesome.

Make sure to backup your data before resizing partitions.

Comment: yes but how? can I do this all within the live boot? or part in the live and part within windows? my plan right now is just to use gparted in live to do it all and hope everything will boot properly afterwards

Comment: @Numnumberry  yes gparted will do it though you might have to install extra packages for the resize.

Comment: I was able to do it in the live boot alone, pretty simple, windows and linux both still boot fine.

Comment: @Numnumberry: Please post a separate answer describing exactly what you did.