# Disk partitioning and resizing

Tags: linux, shell, fdisk, parted

I installed Kali along side windows 10 but I just realized that I allocated too much space for Kali while I am running out of space in windows is there any way I can reallocate some of Kali space for my windows without losing any data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shrink root partition and extend another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373358/how-to-shrink-root-partition-and-extend-another)

Answer (score 0):

- Boot in a live media.
- Fire up GParted/ KDE Partition Manager.
- Edit partition.
  Typical notice: Have a backup, just in case.